# Convert Base64 to Hex in angular 6

Tags: angular, type-conversion, base64, hex

Please could you help me with solving my problem of converting a base64 value to a Hex and vice versa.
I'm currently working on angular 6 and cannot seem to find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function you can use for conversion

```
  hexAndBase64(strInput, conversionType) {
        if (conversionType == "64ToHex") {
            for (var i = 0, bin = atob(strInput.replace(/[ \r\n]+$/, "")), hex = []; i < bin.length; ++i) {
                let tmp = bin.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
                if (tmp.length === 1) tmp = "0" + tmp;
                hex[hex.length] = tmp;
            }
            return hex.join(" ");
        }
        else if (conversionType == "hexTo64") {
            return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
                strInput.replace(/\r|\n/g, "").replace(/([\da-fA-F]{2}) ?/g, "0x$1 ").replace(/ +$/, "").split(" ")));
        }
    }
```

Comment: im am getting this error "Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded."

Comment: It is working fine, I have created demo app here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef4cxx), please check